# run torch on specific multiple CUDA devices

Tags: python, pytorch

this is working sample code it runs roberta on CPU :

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("roberta-large-mnli")
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("roberta-large-mnli")

def test_entailment(text1, text2):
    batch = tokenizer(text1, text2, return_tensors='pt').to(model.device)
    with torch.no_grad():
        proba = torch.softmax(model(**batch).logits, -1)
    return proba.cpu().numpy()[0, model.config.label2id['ENTAILMENT']]

def test_equivalence(text1, text2):
    return test_entailment(text1, text2) * test_entailment(text2, text1)

print(test_equivalence("I'm a good person", "I'm not a good person"))  # 2.0751484e-07
print(test_equivalence("I'm a good person", "You are a good person"))  # 0.49342492
print(test_equivalence("I'm a good person", "I'm not a bad person"))   # 0.94236994
```

i tryed to modify it to run on my CUDA devices 1 and 2

```
device = 'cuda:1'
    torch.set_default_device("cuda")    
    
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("roberta-large-mnli")    
    model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("roberta-large-mnli")  #roberta-large-mnli    
    model.to(torch.device('cuda:1'))
    model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=[1, 2]).cuda()
    # min sollte 0.02 sein und davon die besten 20%   
    lines = Inhaltsverzeichniss(knowledge).splitlines()

    def test_entailment(text1, text2):
        batch = tokenizer(text1, text2, return_tensors='pt').to(model)
        with torch.no_grad():
            proba = torch.softmax(model(**batch).logits, -1)
        return proba.cpu().numpy()[0, model.config.label2id['ENTAILMENT']]

    def test_equivalence(text1, text2):
        return test_entailment(text1, text2) * test_entailment(text2, text1)
```

it always run on my last cuda device ( i have 0, 1 and 2 - 3 Total devices) it only runs on device 2 and gives me also the error: RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:1 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cuda:2